# Play Framework WebSocket Chat Example deploy on heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework

I'm trying to use the Play Framework starting with the WebSocket Chat Example founded here:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.0/samples/scala/websocket-chat

In particular this review of the last Play Framework version:

https://github.com/Shauli10/websocket-chat

I have deployed it on a Free Heroku Account, you can visit it ad this address:

https://desolate-shelf-8169.herokuapp.com

the problem is that when I insert the name, and I chat some message I can't see anything of what i send in the chat, and I can't also see the Robot that in the example type every 30 seconds a message, what I wrong? there is something I have to enable on Heroku for the WebSocket?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that if I change the `https` part of the url to `http` (i.e. http://desolate-shelf-8169.herokuapp.com) your app seems to work. I'm not entirely sure why, but I know some browsers are picky about this with websockets.

[Websockets should work on Heroku out-of-the-box](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websockets). There is nothing that needs to be enabled.

Also, when I tried the template app:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:Shauli10/websocket-chat.git
$ heroku create
$ git push heroku master
```

It seems to "just work". If you are still having trouble, can you explain what you have changed in the template?

Comment: Thank you so much! i haven't tried the http but only the https!